# getElementsByClassName Not Allowing Me To Work With InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I've tried to find answers from previous threads, but nothing has solved my issue this far. I am attempting to implement a function that runs immediately on a page that inserts HTML into divs with specific classes. Here is my code thus far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    divs = document.getElementsByClassName( 'didyouknow' );
  [].slice.call( divs ).forEach(function ( div ) {
    div.innerHTML = "Insert HTML here";
});
}
```

I actually received the advice to use the slice method from another thread on here. Any further assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You just misspelled and forgot `)`. Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9a5gantp/

Comment: post html as well

Comment: Muhammad, thank you for your reply! You have found the issue and I feel silly it was something that simple. Thank you for taking the time to help me.